# SYN Port Scanner Script: "Mac address to reach destination not found. Using Broadcast" error

Tags: python, scapy

Im writing a SYN Port Scanner in Python with Scapy. There are no syntax errors involved but when I run the script Im unable to send any packets to any destination.

[image]

This the code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#Port Scanner using SYN Scanning (Half Open TCP Scanning)

from scapy.all import *
import sys, argparse


#the 'argparse' module makes it easy to write user-freindly command-line interfaces. 
#it also automatically generates help and usage messages and issues errors on invalid arguments

argParser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='TCP SYN Scanner for a single host.')
argParser.add_argument('--version','-v',action='version', version = '%(prog)s is at version 1.0.0')
argParser.add_argument('host',metavar = 'host', type=str, help='The hostname or IP to scan.')
argParser.add_argument('-p', metavar='port', nargs=2, type=str, help='port range scan eg 80 443')
argParser.add_argument('-t', metavar = 'timeout', type=float, help = 'The time to wait for ACKs.', default=1)
arguments = argParser.parse_args()

print 'Scanning host %s' % (arguments.host)

startPort = 1
endPort = 65535

if arguments.p != None: #if we have arguments
    startPort = int(arguments.p[0])
    endPort = int(arguments.p[1])

for port in xrange (startPort, endPort +1):
    packet=sr1(IP(dst=arguments.host)/TCP(dport=port,flags='S'),verbose=0,timeout=arguments.t) //ERROR 
    if packet:
        print ('Port %d is open!' % port)
```

[image]

NOTE: The other question with the same error has a completely different script. Please dont mark as duplicate.

Comment: Could you run in Scapy `>>> conf.route` and post what you get?

Comment: @Pierre Done. Also Im running on NAT mode but it shouldn't matter, I tried Bridge mode as well on the VM

Comment: Just to be sure, have you tried to `nc` your target host & port?

Comment: @Pierre what do you mean nc?

Comment: `nc` (netcat) is a command line tool. Run it like that `nc -vv host port` to make sure it works and it's a Scapy issue.

Comment: @Pierre I can only connect to port 80 (go figure), but it works.e.g. if I put  *nc -vv [host] [port]*

Answer (score 0):

Im an idiot. You cannot put a public IP address, as PAT isn't applicable - it has to be private Class A, B or C. It said that on the first sentence of the GITHUB info paragraph where I took the script from